# Is $2\pi$ not in the same equivalence class as $\pi$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, equivalence-relations

Is $2\pi$ not in the same equivalence class as $\pi$? This is my first encounter with equivalence classes, so I'm just trying to make sure I understand the definition.

---

We write $x \sim y$, when $x-y \in \mathbb{Q}$.

$2\pi -\pi = \pi \notin \mathbb{Q} \implies 2\pi \nsim \pi$

---

Seems simple enough. However, it doesn't sound right. This is, in my mind, the same thing as saying: every irrational number belongs to a different equivalence class than all other irrational numbers, besides rational translations of itself. That just seems, I don't know, too trivial of a property. I would expect, for example, something like $2\sqrt{5} \sim \sqrt 5$.

Comment: "I would expect, for example, something like $2\sqrt{5}\sim \sqrt{5}$" Expect from what? What prior intuition are you trying to apply here? You are simply given a new property that says that $x\sim y$ iff $x-y\in \mathbb{Q}$. There is no reason to expect this property to be anything deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right - for this equivalence relationship $2\pi$ and $\pi$ are not equivalent to each other.

There is no one definitive equivalence relationship on any set; we can (and do) study multiple different equivalence relationships depending on the problem we're trying to solve. The particular equiv. rel. you've given here does strike me as on the trivial side, and you don't need to understand anything deeper about it. Although (SPOILER!) this equiv. rel. is used to prove the existence of unmeasurable sets, but you'll only see this if you go on to study measure theory and Lebesgue integration.

BTW, if you wanted $2\sqrt{5} \sim_2 \sqrt{5} $ you could define 
$$x \sim_2 y \iff x/y \in \mathbb{Q}$$ (for $x,y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$), which would be a second, different equivalence relationship. Of course now $1+\pi$ and $\pi$ are no longer equivalent.

Comment: @JonathonZ Yep, next section was the construction of an unmeasurable set in $\mathbb{R}$, thank you.

Comment: That's so funny. Yeah, I'd only seen this used to prove unmeasurable sets, and nothing beyond that. It's kind of a "make it, use it once, then throw it away" type of mathematical construction, nothing deeper.

Comment: Something else you might want to notice is that this particular equivalence relationship is specifically chosen to work with a property of the measure on $\mathbb{R}$ - translation invariance. If we had a problem with a different measure we might choose to define a different equivalence relationship.